# MySQL Query Filter Sequenced by two date columns

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I wanted to arranged my table in a proper sequence of date to both the `date_due` column and `date_paid` column.

My table structure shows like this and it is ordered by the `due_date` column:

```
Period      Due Date        Paid Date
                            12/01/2014
                            02/05/2014
1           01/01/2015
2           02/01/2015
3           03/01/2015
4           04/01/2015
```

Then all I want is to do this:

```
Period       Due Date       Paid Date
                            12/01/2014
1            01/01/2015
2            02/01/2015
                            02/05/2014
3            03/01/2015
4            04/01/2015
```

Comment: please write your query.

Comment: Can you add the table creation statement?

Comment: Here is my query:

SELECT * FROM proj_loan_management_db.loan_ledger order by $due_date;

Comment: @MisterHenson How would i do that?

Comment: But the greatest function is to get the greatest value in a fields but then the question is how do we able to make an orderly sequence that would follow the above rules? order by function for both the due_date column and date_paid column doesnt seems have a good outcome either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok forget about my stupid comment - it was not constructive. First of all I think you have a mistake in your data: I guess "02/05/2014" should be "02/05/2015".

The problem is that you have to aggregate the two columns, to be able to sort after that. Using the `GREATEST` function like I stated in my comment actually would not work, because it is not null-save. You can use for example the `COALESCE` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) here.

All in all this can either be done by "adding a column" like

```
SELECT 
  *, Coalesce(`Due Date`, `Paid Date`) as bananas
FROM 
  table1
ORDER BY
  bananas
```

Or add the expression directly to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  table1
ORDER BY
  Coalesce(`Due Date`, `Paid Date`)
```

Please see this fiddle and try yourself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21a84/1

Comment: Sir! this code work perfectly! respect to you sir, and thank you very much for this help. i salute you!